# Scalable database technology and architecture

Tags: database, scalability, rdbms, distributed, nosql

I've been trying to learn more about database scaling in a distributed system, and I am stuck in between RDBMS and NoSQL.

Some articles online suggest that NoSQL is the solution to modern Big Data. Others say NoSQL is just a hype and RDBMS can be just as scalable with good design, and it provides good data structure.

Instead of reading others' opinions, I'd love to judge the two myself, but I do not understand exactly what is required for a scalable RDBMS and a scalable NoSQL.

I've done a bit more readings on RDBMS, and it seems that the solution requires leveraging memcache and sharding to reduce database size and the number of DB queries. Are there other tricks? Can you still use tables with many columns? Or use less columns and more joins?

As for NoSQL, I've read a little about MongoDB. I understand that it encourages data aggregation. But how does that make it more scalable? I'm also starting to learn Cassandra because I read that it scales much better than MongoDB, but I have no idea how it is more scalable.

I would very much appreciate a basic (or advanced, if you have the patience to type it out) condensed and down-to-the-core explanation on scaling RDBMS and NoSQL, or good articles online or books that explain the topic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't cover ways you can scale by implementing things on your own and putting a memcache server in between, ... I'll just cover what comes right out of the box...

Let's start first with **RDBMS**:

I think setting up an RDBMS cluster is more complicated than a NoSQL cluster, but that's just my opinion. Usually what you have is one Master and multiple Slaves. You have to send all your writes to the master and can read from any slave you want. Since you have RDBMS and ACID, the system should somehow guarantee you, that you won't read old data. So the thing here is, that you assume that your application writes once and reads often (as it's usually the case). For those purposes, one Server for read/write and multiple servers for read is great. The problem is if you'r writes are so often that you can't keep up with them anymore on the one machine. That is your bottleneck. Additionally to the build in solutions from Oracle for instance - which are huge - there is also http://www.scalearc.com/ which can cache queries, ... and handle the scaling for you.

**NoSQL**:

There is no 1 NoSQL schema which is implemented by all the DBs. Every system is a bit different. MongoDB for instance is quite similar to RDBMS, it also has only one Master and several slaves to which it can replicate data, but additionally you can also create shards. Data is split between shards, and replicated to slaves. So you could have multiple different masters which are responsible for smaller parts. Afterwards when you read, you can choose if you want to read from multiple slaves, from the master or from any slave - depending how urgently you need the latest data.

Cassandra on the other hand works totally differently. I'm not sure if you can write to multiple servers or how it works, but basically the servers keep a log of all the writes. So even if they can't process the writes immediately, they are stored in a log, to still give you a fast response. Afterwards when you read, you can say again how urgently you want to have the new data, and if you really want the latest latest data, Cassandra will need to check the log, if there are any updates written, and it will cost you a lot of time.

Key-Value stores like ElasticSearch, CouchDB, CouchBase work again differently. Here the of the item is hashed, and based on the hash, sent to one node which will be responsible for it. This way, when you read after the key was written, you get again up to date information, because you'll read from the same node. The idea of this design is, that no one single key will be of everyone's interest, but the load will be distributed. These are also the DBs which I think scale the best, and make it the easiest to add more servers to the cluster, but you loose the power of complex queries, like you have it in MongoDB and Cassandra - and of course RDBMS. ElasticSearch has some simple search queries, and CouchDB and CouchBase have only Views which are produced by MapReduce, where you can get data which you want, if it fits the view. Otherwise you can only access it by the key.

http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis - is a very comprehensive summary of the most common NoSQL DBs, what are their strengths and weaknesses, and the most common usage scenarios.

---

In the end, the question is also, why do you want to scale? how many records are you going to have in the database? Few millions is not a problem at all. Few hundred millions is also not a problem for most of the RDBMS on a powerful enough server. And if designed the DB and it's indices properly even a billion records per year should be still fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed response! It's fascinating that there are so many approaches to scalability, especially among NoSQL DBs. I will need to do more studying on each approach. It seems I can judge the technologies for a particular problem only if I understand how each of them work fundamentally. I think it's still a bit early to accept an answer so I'll do it in a day or so.